# PostgreSQL column values must be in a sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, restriction

How would I define a column in PostgreSQL such that each value must be in a sequence, not the sequence you get when using type `serial` but one such that a value 2 cannot be inserted unless there exists a value 1 already in the column?

Comment: Are gaps allowed? What about deletions or updates that change the column's value?

Comment: This is just theoretical, I was wondering how to do it if it was needed. But I would say that such deletions and updates should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you could use a constraint that worked like this. (But it won't work in practice.)

1. Count the rows.
2. Evaluate `max(column) - min(column) + 1`.
3. Compare the results.

You'd probably have to insert one row before creating the CHECK constraint. If you didn't, max(column) would return NULL. With one row,

1. Count the rows (1).
2. Evaluate `max(column) - min(column) + 1`. (1 - 1 + 1 = 1)
3. Compare the results. (1 = 1)

With 10 rows . .

1. Count the rows (10).
2. Evaluate `max(column) - min(column) + 1`. (10 - 1 + 1 = 10)
3. Compare the results. (10 = 10)

It doesn't matter whether the sequence starts at 1; this way of checking will always show a gap if one exists.  If you needed to guarantee that the gapless sequence started at 1, you could add that to the CHECK constraint.

As far as I know, there isn't any way to do this declaratively with any current dbms. To do it, you'd need support for `CREATE ASSERTION`. (But I could be wrong.) In PostgreSQL, I think your only shot at this involves procedural code in multiple AFTER triggers.

I only have one table that needs to be gapless. It's a calendar table. We run a query once a night that does these calculations, and it lets me know whether I have a gap.

Comment: You can do it with explicit locking. Just `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before the `INSERT`, so you block everything except `SELECT`.

Comment: I *think* the point was whether a declarative constraint could guarantee a gapless sequence. (The OP *might* not have meant that, but that's want I was aiming at.) An exclusive lock on the table can guarantee a gapless insert, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So it can really one be done with an `AFTER` trigger as you noted - and even then you have to rely on trigger ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a detailed example of a gapless sequence implementation using PL/PgSQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985219/398670).

The general idea is that you want a table to store the sequence values, and you use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` followed by `UPDATE` - or the shorthand `UPDATE ... RETURNING` - to get values from it while locking the row until your transaction commits or rolls back.

Answer (score -1):

You write an `on insert tigger` or a `check constraint`. However, this will still allow to delete "1" afterwards and "2" stays in the table, you'll probably have to address this too.

Comment: I thought of a check constraint but how would I write it?

Comment: untested, should be something like: `... v integer check (v > select max(v) from mytable)` or `check (v = (select max(v) from mytable) + 1)`

Comment: A check constraint won't work. A check constraint should be true for each row all the time so you'd have problems when doing updates.